# Replace function in React with Quill Formulas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace, quill, radix

I use replace function in following way and it works perfectly: `choice.value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')`
However when I work with `Quill Formulas`, such as  `√5`, it converts it to the string: `5\sqrt{5}5`. Is it possible to fix it so it displays it with all formula symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) and its React implementation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax) or the [React Latex package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-latex)

I think that using `.replace` to handle latex strings will only get you so far, as you can see in your problem. But you can use `.replace()` to get it readable for some of the packages I mentioned. I would try something like:

`MathJax.something(choice.value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ''))`